# Find and turn off resources that were activated by Vertex AI but not turned off by it

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We recently turned on Vertex AI for a small test. After finding out we were getting charged £1k a month for almost zero processing we turned the instance off. I am still getting charged £600 a month for other items that the billing reports confirm is part of this set up:
"{
""service"": {
""id"": ""C7E2-9256-1C43"",
""description"": ""Vertex AI""
}
}"

"{
""sku"": {
""id"": ""D564-0029-7DB4"",
""description"": ""Vertex AI: Online/Batch Prediction N1 Predefined Instance Ram running in Netherlands for AI Platform""
}
}"

I can locate the devices in the billing section but not anywhere in the interface to be able to turn them off. Does anyone know how I can find them and stop them?

As a side note, I have tried to buy a support package to help with this, but despite the fact I pay the bills the systems say I don't have the correct permissions to place an order for paid support on Google Cloud Services. If anyone knows how to get around that while I'm at it I'd appreciate it. Fivetran created the instance, so perhaps they have permissions.